# Half screen Fixed, other half has text-scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, transition

I'm trying to create a website where half the page it fixed and the other half can scroll through content (similar to the 'your life with nest' section here https://nest.com/thermostat/meet-nest-thermostat/). Does anyone know a template I could use to begin to do this? I'm very very new to coding, but know basic HTML and some javascript.

I'd want to have 5 overall sections, where in each section I'd have 1 fixed image on one side, and then can scroll through 3 sets of copy content on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

give your sidebar an id for ex . < tag id = "side" >

on Css Stylesheet Write this code

```
    #side 
   {
     width   : 100px;   // width of your Side bar 
     height  : 600px;   // height of Your Side bar 
     float   : left ;   // You can float it right or left 
     position: fixed;   // to prevent it from Scrolling 
     z-index : 999;     // give it any big number to make it above elements on the page 

   }
```

and you can use Jquery to remove this id when scrolling to a specific height  and gives this id to The next fixed Section  .... and So on

### Updated

You can also use JS libraries Like What @Ouroborus mentioned To